# Unable to populate/update a data into another JTable "B" onclick on a specific row in JTable "A"

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two class `placeNewOrder` and the main class `DeliveryExpressApp`.

The problem is when I select the first row in the available restaurants `JTable` it must load the data which I specified in the comment in my code into the Menu table.

I have put the code for the two classes in the link below.

http://txt.do/5nx9p or http://textuploader.com/5nx9p!

Comment: *"I have put the code for the two classes in the link below."* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (And post it here as an edit to the question, not at some link(s) that some can't follow, and most won't.)

Comment: *"The problem is when I select the first row in the available restaurants JTable it must load the data which I specified in the comment in my code into the Menu table."* ..why is that a problem?

Comment: No way anyone is gona read all that code.

Comment: oh alright but my problem is the program is working only that is not doing what i wanted there is no compile error...i was thinking it will more better for the group to run the code so they can understand better what my problem is :(                                                                                                                And i've also put some line of comment as to where the helper should focus on. to get the idea of the problem

Comment: *"i was thinking it will more better for the group to run the code"* Yes, that is part of the point of making an MCVE/SSCCE. So where is yours? And a tip: Add @Heinzlmaen (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: thanx for your concern ...my mistake...i was using this sign //++++++++++++++ to notify the selection where my problem is.. thanx Heinzlmaen

Comment: this is the new modification link http://txt.do/5nxke or http://textuploader.com/5nxke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, I thınk the problem is your are creating a new table every time a selection occurs.

```
 public JTable menuTableMethod(String []title, String [][]data){
        menuTable = new JTable(data, title);
```

Create tables while initializing the class and use table models for refreshing tables. I changed the below parts and program is working now. But still you must do some changes and use all tables with table models.

Initialize members:

```
JTable availableRestaurantsTable,  orderSummaryTable;

DefaultTableModel defaultModel = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable menuTable = new JTable(defaultModel);
```

menuTableMethod

```
public JTable menuTableMethod(String []title, String [][]data){
    //menuTable = new JTable(data, title);
    defaultModel.setDataVector(data, title);

    menuTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(380, 250));
    //menuTable.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    menuTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    menuTable.updateUI();
    menuTable.validate();
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table update ! ");

    return menuTable;
}
```

mouse adapter

```
    availableRestaurantsTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            String cellValue = (String)availableRestaurantsTable.getValueAt(availableRestaurantsTable.getSelectedRow(), availableRestaurantsTable.getSelectedColumn());

            if(cellValue.compareTo("Bar & Boeuf") == 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yeap! Same\n"+cellValue);
                menuTableMethod(title2, dataUpdate);
            }

        }
```

Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for more information about table models.

Comment: thanx so much rdonuk you are the man....my problem is TableModel for refreshing table...now my program is working prefectly... :)